# D3 - display x value data ticks as percentages

Tags: javascript, web, d3.js

Have a line graph shown as here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V54Wu.jpg
Would love the x-axis to display a & sign after each tick, 10%, 20%, etc. How does one accomplish this?

I've read up on a format method one can use, as well as saw people using Math and actually doing a conversion, but figure there must be a quick way to add a string % after each tick, surely!

Using V4 of D3 here

```
    <script>
        // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
        const formatPercent = d3.format(".0%")
        const margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 60, left: 250},
            width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        
        // append the svg object to the body of the page
        const svg = d3.select(".line")
          .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        
        // Parse the Data
        d3.json("./data/linedata.json", function(data) {
        
          // Add X axis
          const x = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, 100])
            .range([ 0, width]);
          svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
            .selectAll("text").attr('class', 'xaxis')
              .attr("transform", "translate(0,0 )")
              
              .style("text-anchor", "end");
        
          // Y axis
          const y = d3.scaleBand()
            .range([ 0, height ])
            .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.desc; }))
            .padding(.1)
          svg.append("g").attr('class', 'xaxis')
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        
          //Bars
          svg.selectAll("myRect")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", x(0) )
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.desc); })
            .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.total); })
            .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )
            .attr("fill", "#008080")
        
        })
        
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the tickFormat function?
Something like this should work:

> .tickFormat(d => d + "%")